# What is PreviousID

Tags: spfield, schema

I have a field in my list and not sure why it has PreviousID attribute.

I have the same list in the same farm but in the different web application and does not have this attribute.

```
<Field Type="Choice" DisplayName="Status" Name="Status" Required="TRUE" Description="DESC" Format="Dropdown" ID="{GUID}" SourceID="{GUID}" StaticName="Status" ColName="nvarchar1" RowOrdinal="0" Version="2" PreviousID="{GUID}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/897c8d87-0098-4961-a57e-b62cda4f80c4/previousid-attribute-on-field-element?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)?

It appears to be a field added by SharePoint itself, especially when there is some kind of conflict with one of the fields in the list.

Not sure if it helps much, but there doesn't seem to be any actual documentation to support this.

Comment: Thanks Tiago. But that did not helped me.